# jaxb-bindingx.xml “results in too many target nodes”

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xsd, jaxb

I'm trying to generate java class from `wsdl` but I get error:

> XPath evaluation of
>   "//xs:element[@name='RZECZ_REJESTRACJA']\xs:complexType/xs:choice\xs:sequencexs:element[@ref='NUMER_OZNAKOWANIA']"
>   results in too many (2) target nodes

My file XSD - `kcik_rejestracja_przedmiotu.xsd`:

```
<xs:element name="RZECZ_REJESTRACJA">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="NUMER_FABRYCZNY"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="NUMER_OZNAKOWANIA"/>
      <xs:element ref="MARKA_RZECZY"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="TYP_RZECZY"/>
      <xs:element ref="RODZAJ_RZECZY"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="NUMER_OZNAKOWANIA"/>
      <xs:element ref="MARKA_RZECZY"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="TYP_RZECZY"/>
      <xs:element ref="RODZAJ_RZECZY"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

And my `jaxb-bindings.xml` which didn't work.:

```
  <bindings schemaLocation="wsdl/SOAComponents/ApplicationObjectLibrary/KCIK/Service/schemas/kcik_rejestracja_przedmiotu.xsd">
  <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='RZECZ_REJESTRACJA']/xs:complexType/xs:choice/xs:sequence">
      <bindings node=".//xs:element[@ref='NUMER_OZNAKOWANIA']">
            <property name="NumerOznakowaniaAttr"/>
      </bindings>
  </bindings>
```

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Yes. 
XPath evaluation of "//xs:element[@name='RZECZ_REJESTRACJA']\xs:complexType/xs:choice\xs:sequencexs:element[@ref='NUMER_OZNAKOWANIA']" results in too many (2) target nodes

Answer (score 0):

You may use this binding file

```
<bindings node="//xs:element[@name='RZECZ_REJESTRACJA']/xs:complexType/xs:choice/xs:sequence[1]">
      <bindings node=".//xs:element[@ref='NUMER_OZNAKOWANIA']">
            <property name="NumerOznakowaniaAttr"/>
      </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Comment: I resolved this problem.

`<bindings version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">  
<globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">
   <xjc:simple /> 
</globalBindings>`

Answer (score -1):

Your XSD should be rewritten as follow

```
 <xs:element name="RZECZ_REJESTRACJA">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="NUMER_FABRYCZNY"/>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
         <xs:element  ref="NUMER_OZNAKOWANIA"/>
      </xs:sequence/
      <xs:element ref="MARKA_RZECZY"/>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
         <xs:element ref="TYP_RZECZY"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="RODZAJ_RZECZY"/>
    </xs:sequence>     
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: I think I can't modify model, because it is generated from the external system.